# How to select and return data using FKs in Yii2 RESTful API?

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I managed to write the REST API code and it works for the standard actions.

Now, if I want to send more `attributes`, like `url_to_api_action?a=b&c=d&e=f`, this does not match any of the standard actions.

I need to search by attributes, using a RESTful API in Yii2.

any ideas?

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UneController extends ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'common\models\Une';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm elaborating the answer

add search action mentioned in this link to the controller

[Yii2 REST query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query)

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
/**
* Country Controller API
*
* @author Budi Irawan <deerawan@gmail.com>
*/
class CountryController extends ActiveController
{
public $modelClass = 'api\modules\v1\models\Country'; 
public $serializer = [
    'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
    'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
];

public function actionSearch()
{
if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $model = new $this->modelClass;
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        if (!$model->hasAttribute($key)) {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Invalid attribute:' . $key);
        }
    }
    try {
        $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $model->find()->where($_GET),
            'pagination' => false
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(500, 'Internal server error');
    }

    if ($provider->getCount() <= 0) {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'No entries found with this query string');
    } 
    else {
        return $provider;
    }
} 
else {
    throw new \yii\web\HttpException(400, 'There are no query string');
  }

 } 
}
```

And add **urlManager** like below in the **config/main.php**
[Cant use tockens and extrapattern together for REST services in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167458/cant-use-tockens-and-extrapattern-together-for-rest-services-in-yii2)

```
        'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/country',
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET search' => 'search'
                    ],                 
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/country',
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                ]

            ],

        ],        
    ]
```

therefor we can use both default actions of the activecontroller and our custom actions together

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own actions inside the controller, and you just need to return the result from Active Record and it will take care of formatting the data.

```
public function actionSearch($keyword)
{
    $result = YourModel::find()
              ->where(['keyword' => $keyword])
              ->all();
    return $result;
}
```

More details here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest.html#creating-controllers-and-actions

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionSearch($keyword)
{
    $result = YourModel::find()
              ->with('model relation')
              ->where(['keyword' => $keyword])
              ->all();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Some aditional explanations ?