# Yii2 REST query

Tags: api, rest, yii2

Hy. 
I have a ProductController which extends the yii\rest\ActiveController.
Question is that how can i make querys via HTTP GET request.

Like: http://api.test.loc/v1/products/search?name=iphone

And the return object will contains all products with name iphone.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok i figured out, just put this in your Controller and modifiy the URL router in config.

```
public function actionSearch()
{
    if (!empty($_GET)) {
        $model = new $this->modelClass;
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            if (!$model->hasAttribute($key)) {
                throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Invalid attribute:' . $key);
            }
        }
        try {
            $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $model->find()->where($_GET),
                'pagination' => false
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(500, 'Internal server error');
        }

        if ($provider->getCount() <= 0) {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'No entries found with this query string');
        } else {
            return $provider;
        }
    } else {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(400, 'There are no query string');
    }
}
```

And the URL rule (edit)

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['v1/product'], 'extraPatterns' => ['GET search' => 'search']],
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: what do you modify in router? You must be comprehensive to help others in future

Comment: Ok i modified. Sorry i'm new here :D

Answer (score 47):

### **UPDATE: Apr 29 2016**

This is one more approach simpler than the one I introduced in the previous update. It is always about involving the **Search** class generated by **gii**. I like using it to define and maintain all the search related logic in a single place like using custom scenarios, handle validations, or involve related models on the filtering process (like in this [example](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/blob/cc01d7179cb93936dd74945f0173cbc1725f2963/backend/models/searches/ImageSearch.php)). So I'm going back to my first answer :

```
public function actions() 
{ 
    $actions = parent::actions();
    $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'prepareDataProvider'];
    return $actions;
}

public function prepareDataProvider() 
{
    $searchModel = new \app\models\ProductSearch();    
    return $searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
}
```

Then be sure that your search class is using `load($params,'')` instead of `load($params)` or alternatively add this to the **model** class:

```
class Product extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function formName()
    {
        return '';
    }
```

That should be enough to have your requests looking like:

### /products?name=iphone&status=available&sort=name,-price

---

### **UPDATE: Sep 23 2015**

This is the same approach but by implementing a complete & cleaner solution :

```
namespace app\api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;

class ProductController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Product';
    // Some reserved attributes like maybe 'q' for searching all fields at once 
    // or 'sort' which is already supported by Yii RESTful API
    public $reservedParams = ['sort','q'];

    public function actions() {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        // 'prepareDataProvider' is the only function that need to be overridden here
        $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'indexDataProvider'];
        return $actions;
    }

    public function indexDataProvider() {
        $params = \Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

        $model = new $this->modelClass;
        // I'm using yii\base\Model::getAttributes() here
        // In a real app I'd rather properly assign 
        // $model->scenario then use $model->safeAttributes() instead
        $modelAttr = $model->attributes;

        // this will hold filtering attrs pairs ( 'name' => 'value' )
        $search = [];

        if (!empty($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
                // In case if you don't want to allow wired requests
                // holding 'objects', 'arrays' or 'resources'
                if(!is_scalar($key) or !is_scalar($value)) {
                    throw new BadRequestHttpException('Bad Request');
                }
                // if the attr name is not a reserved Keyword like 'q' or 'sort' and 
                // is matching one of models attributes then we need it to filter results
                if (!in_array(strtolower($key), $this->reservedParams) 
                    && ArrayHelper::keyExists($key, $modelAttr, false)) {
                    $search[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        // you may implement and return your 'ActiveDataProvider' instance here.
        // in my case I prefer using the built in Search Class generated by Gii which is already 
        // performing validation and using 'like' whenever the attr is expecting a 'string' value.
        $searchByAttr['ProductSearch'] = $search;
        $searchModel = new \app\models\ProductSearch();    
        return $searchModel->search($searchByAttr);     
    }
}
```

Now your GET request will look like :

### /products?name=iphone

Or even like :

### /products?name=iphone&status=available&sort=name,-price

- **Note:**

  If instead of `/products?name=iphone` you are looking for a specific
  action to handle searching or filtering requests like :

  ### /products/search?name=iphone

  Then, in the code above you'll need to **remove** the actions function with all its content :

  ```
  public function actions() { ... }
  ```

  **rename** :`indexDataProvider()` to `actionSearch()`

  & finally **add** `'extraPatterns' => ['GET search' => 'search']` to your    *yii\web\UrlManager::rules* as described
  in @KedvesHunor's answer.

---

### **Original answer: May 31 2015**

There is a short way to do this, if when using *Gii* to generate CRUD for your model, you defined a *Search Model Class*, then you can use it to filter results, all you have to do is to override the `prepareDataProvider` function of `indexAction` to force it return the `ActiveDataProvider` instance returned by the `search` function of your model *search class* rather than creating a custom new one.

To resume if your model is **Product.php** & you generated a **ProductSearch.php** as a *search class* to it, then in your *Controller* you just need to add this :

```php
public function actions() {

    $actions = parent::actions();
    $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'prepareDataProvider'];

    return $actions;
}

public function prepareDataProvider() {

    $searchModel = new \app\models\ProductSearch();    
    return $searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
}
```

Then to filter results, your url may look like this :

```php
api.test.loc/v1/products?ProductSearch[name]=iphone
```

or even like this :

```php
api.test.loc/v1/products?ProductSearch[available]=1&ProductSearch[name]=iphone
```

Comment: I think it is better to use \Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams() method

Comment: @TomoMiha Any particular reason for that? Any getter function in Yii like `getXxx()` can be called as a property `xxx`, so calling `Yii::$app->request->queryParams` is actually a mapper to `Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParams()`. So AFAIK it is just a matter of preference. More about it [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-properties).

Comment: @Querdani Ok, but using it as a method gives me IDE auto-completion, and nice docs while hovering it. And, if the method is later upgraded with parameters they will be displayed here on hover.

Answer (score 8):

I would not recommend to use Superglobals $_GET directly . Instead you can use `Yii::$app->request->get()`.

Following  is the example how you can create a generic search action and use it in the controller.

At the controller End

```
public function actions() {

$actions = [
    'search' => [
        'class'       => 'app\[YOUR NAMESPACE]\SearchAction',
        'modelClass'  => $this->modelClass,
        'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
        'params'      => \Yii::$app->request->get()
    ],
];

return array_merge(parent::actions(), $actions);
}

public function verbs() {

    $verbs = [
        'search'   => ['GET']
    ];
    return array_merge(parent::verbs(), $verbs);
}
```

Custom Search Action

````
<?php

namespace app\[YOUR NAMESPACE];

use Yii;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use yii\rest\Action;


class SearchAction extends Action {

    /**
     * @var callable a PHP callable that will be called to prepare a data provider that
     * should return a collection of the models. If not set, [[prepareDataProvider()]] will be used instead.
     * The signature of the callable should be:
     *
     * ```php
     * function ($action) {
     *     // $action is the action object currently running
     * }
     * ```
     *
     * The callable should return an instance of [[ActiveDataProvider]].
     */
    public $prepareDataProvider;
    public $params;

    /**
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function run() {
        if ($this->checkAccess) {
            call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id);
        }

        return $this->prepareDataProvider();
    }

    /**
     * Prepares the data provider that should return the requested collection of the models.
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    protected function prepareDataProvider() {
        if ($this->prepareDataProvider !== null) {
            return call_user_func($this->prepareDataProvider, $this);
        }

        /**
         * @var \yii\db\BaseActiveRecord $modelClass
         */
        $modelClass = $this->modelClass;

        $model = new $this->modelClass([
        ]);

        $safeAttributes = $model->safeAttributes();
        $params = array();

        foreach($this->params as $key => $value){
            if(in_array($key, $safeAttributes)){
               $params[$key] = $value;                
            }
        }

        $query = $modelClass::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if (empty($params)) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }


        foreach ($params as $param => $value) {
            $query->andFilterWhere([
                $param => $value,
            ]);
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }

}
````

Answer (score 3):

Since yii 2.0.13, `yii\rest\IndexAction` has new property, - `dataFilter`, which simplifies the filtering process. By default ActiveController uses `yii\rest\IndexAction` for the `index` action:

```
    class ActiveController extends Controller {
        public function actions()
        {
            return [
                'index' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\IndexAction',
                    'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
                    'checkAccess' => [$this, 'checkAccess'],
                ]
        }
}
```

Do the following in the `ProductController` controller:

```
class ProductController extends ActiveController
{
    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();

        $actions['index']['dataFilter'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\data\ActiveDataFilter',
            'searchModel' => 'app\models\ProductSearch'
        ];

        return $actions;
    }
}
```

Assume `app\models\ProductSearch` is Product filter model.

Comment: if you are looking for filters this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

**In Config/web.php -> Add 'extraPatterns' => ['GET search' => 'search']**

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'v1/basicinfo', 'pluralize'=>false,'extraPatterns' => ['GET search' => 'search']]]]
```

**In Rest Api Controller :-  Moduels/v1/controllers/ **

**basicinfo :- Is your controller Name , Name and age is your Fields Name.you can add all parameters exist in your table.**

**Search URL LIKE :- basicinfo/search?name=yogi&age=12-23**

***Include use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;***

```
 public function actionSearch()
{
    if (!empty($_GET)) {
        $model = new $this->modelClass;
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
            if (!$model->hasAttribute($key)) {
                throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Invalid attribute:' . $key);
            }
        }
        try {

           $query = $model->find();
            foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
                 if ($key != 'age') {
                    $query->andWhere(['like', $key, $value]);
                  }
                  if ($key == 'age') {
                  $agevalue = explode('-',$value);
                  $query->andWhere(['between', $key,$agevalue[0],$agevalue[1]]);

             }

            }

            $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
                'sort' => [
                    'defaultOrder' => [
                        'updated_by'=> SORT_DESC
                    ]
                ],
                  'pagination' => [
                'defaultPageSize' => 20,
            ],
            ]);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(500, 'Internal server error');
        }

        if ($provider->getCount() <= 0) {
            throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'No entries found with this query string');
        } else {
            return $provider;
        }
    } else {
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(400, 'There are no query string');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access your api like: `api/product/index?name=fashion` 
a shorter way to filter would be :
-Unset the action, in my case `index` action.

```
public function actions()
{
    $actions = parent::actions(); 
    unset($actions['index']);
    return $actions;
}
```

- Do a custom query as shown below.

  public function actionIndex() {

  ```
  $query = Product::find();
  $dataProvider =  new ActiveDataProvider([
      'query' => $query,
      'pagination' => [
              'pageSize' => 1,
          ],
  ]);

  if (isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])) {
      $searchWord = strtolower(trim($_GET['name']));
      $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $searchWord]);
  }

  return $dataProvider;
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by unique field, here is a shorter version to fetch only one record:

```
    public function actionSearch()
    {
        if (!empty($_GET)) {
            $model = new $this->modelClass;
            return $model::findOne($_GET);
        } else {
            throw new HttpException(400, 'There are no query string');
        }
    }
```

Usage: `http://example.com/api/search?slug=abs`