# Get rest data with some conditions in Yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

It gives me the list of all users when I run this url **"api/web/v1/users"** using get method in Yii2 in its default rest setup.

I have a column **is_active** in the **users** table, so I only want the list of all **active** users "where is_active=1", my question is that how I can pass my custom conditions to get rest data?

Answer (score 2):

This questions contains all the code you need for a general REST query/search implementation in Yii2:
[Yii2 REST query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query)

Your search can be done calling api/web/v1/users/search?is_active=1

Answer (score 1):

add this to your REST controller

```
public function actions()
{
    // Overriding action
    $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = function($action) 
    {
        return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
           'query' => \app\models\User::find()->where(['is_active' => 1]),

        ]);
    };

    return $actions;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by overriding `users` action or creating new action in your `REST` controller:

```
public function actionActiveUsers(){
    return User::find()->where(['active' => 1])->all();
}
```

Now, you can get active users via `user/activeUsers` URL.

Comment: Yes, this solution is creating a new action that I don't want, I just want to use same url "api/web/v1/users" to get the desired result.

Comment: So just override it and rename `actionActiveUsers()` to `actionUsers()`

Comment: I tried actionUsers but it is not overriding the default action, I tried actionIndex also since it is inside "UserController" but it is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

i have done it same task for REST APIs using ActiveDataProvider.

Comment/Disable the line of the UserController 
public $modelClass = 'app\model\user';

create new action i.e., actionIndex()
//--- Controller action

```
public function actionIndex(){

$query = (new yii\db\Query())
->from('user')
->where('ia_active=:rec',[
  ':rec'=>1
]);

$dataProvider = new yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

return $dataProvider;
}
```

Note:
add url-rule in web.php (urlManager)
//---web.php

```
'urlManager' => [
  enablePrettyUrl' => true,
  'rules' = [
    //--- other rules
    'GET,HEAD users' => 'v1/users/index',
  ]
]
```

try it.