# Filter by other fields on Yii2 RESTful API

Tags: php, rest, yii, yii2

First sorry for bad english!

I'm testing a RESTful API in YII2 and it's so easy to create, following the [official guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html). But by default (as far as I know) i can only pass the **id** as param to get a specific record.

For example, supposing that i have the following table called **person**:
`id, name, age, gender, email, phone`

In this case, i can only filter by id, like this: `http://myserver/api/persons/1`

I need to know how to filter by other field, like **age** or **gender** for example.

**My Controller:**

```
class PersonController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Person';
}
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **ActiveDataProvider** instance returned by the default **IndexAction** which is implemented in the **ActiveController** class doesn't support filtering by attributes :

---

*app/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/IndexAction.php :*

```
(...)

protected function prepareDataProvider()
{
    (...)

    return new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $modelClass::find(),
    ]);
}
```

You will need to override it with custom code. here is an example where it is overridden by the **ActiveDataProvider** instance returned by **gii**'s built in **Search Model Class** : [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query/30560912#30560912)