# Yii2 - Override checkAccess in rest ActiveController

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
Product.supplierID = Supplier.supplierID
---------         ----------
|Product|---------|Supplier|
---------         ----------
                       |
                       |  Supplier.supplierID = User.supplierID
                       |
                   ---------
                   |  User |
                   ---------
```

Using the above table structure, the application uses sub-classes of `ActiveController`, with overridden `prepareDataProvider` to limit the `index` list of each `Product` a logged in `User` can see to those with matching `supplierID` values. Something like this in the `actions()` method of `ProductController`.

```
$actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = function($action)
{
    $query = Product::find();
    if (Yii::$app->user->can('supplier') &&
        Yii::$app->user->identity->supplierID) {
        $query->andWhere(['supplierID' => Yii::$app->user->identity->supplierID]);
    }
    return new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);
};
```

This works fine, however I'm looking to use `checkAccess()` to limit `actionView()` for a single `Product`.

At the moment, a logged in `User` can access a `Product` by changing the `productID` in the URL, whether or not the have the appropriate `supplierID`.

It looks like I can't access the particular instance of `Product`, to check the `supplierID`, until `actionView()` has returned which is when I want the check to happen.

Can I override `checkAccess()` to restrict access and throw the appropriate `ForbiddenHttpException`?

Comment: so, you want to disable `product Id` access from url.

Comment: hmm, perhaps? hadn't thought of it from that direction. was more thinking of not returning data that isn't permitted but there might be a solution in not having the `productID` as a `GET` parameter. something to think about certainly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a function that checks if a model exist :

```
protected function modelExist($id)
{
    return Product::find()
    ->where([ 'productID' => $id ])
    ->andWhere(['supplierID' => Yii::$app->user->identity->supplierID ])
    ->exists(); 
}
```

If `productID` is your Product Primary Key, then a request to `/products/1` will be translated by *yii\rest\UrlRule* to `/products?productID=1`.

In that case, when `productID` is provided as a *param*, you can use `beforeAction` to make a quick check if such model exist & let the action be executed or throw an error if it doesn't :

```
// this array will hold actions to which you want to perform a check
public $checkAccessToActions   = ['view','update','delete'];

public function beforeAction($action) {
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action)) return false;

        $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;

        if (isset($params['productID']) {
           foreach ($this->checkAccessToActions as $action) {
              if ($this->action->id === $action) {
                  if ($this->modelExist($params['productID']) === false)
                       throw new NotFoundHttpException("Object not found");
              }
           }
    }
    return true;
}
```

---

## update

As the question is about **Overriding the checkAccess method in rest ActiveController** I thought it would be useful to leave an example.

In the way how Yii2 REST was designed, all of `delete`, `update` and `view` actions will invoke the `checkAccess` method once the model instance is loaded:

```php
// code snippet from yii\rest\ViewAction
$model = $this->findModel($id);
if ($this->checkAccess) {
    call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id, $model);
}
```

The same is true for the `create` and `index` actions except that they won't pass any model instance to it: `call_user_func($this->checkAccess, $this->id)`.

So what you are trying to do (*throwing a [ForbiddenHttpException](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-forbiddenhttpexception.html) when a user is trying to view, update or delete a product he is not its supplier*) may also be achieved this way:

```php
public function checkAccess($action, $model = null, $params = [])
{
    if ($action === 'view' or $action === 'update' or $action === 'delete') 
    {
        if ( Yii::$app->user->can('supplier') === false
             or Yii::$app->user->identity->supplierID === null
             or $model->supplierID !== \Yii::$app->user->identity->supplierID ) 
        {
             throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You can\'t '.$action.' this product.');
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @SalemOerdany; this is similar to what i have at the moment, using a helper method (not `checkAccess`) which throws appropriately, custom `actionMethods` and calling the method at the top of each overridden "action" method. your solution feels a bit more idiomatic Yii though. i'm going to give your idea a go and will report back. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I've always seen the [checkAccess](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#performing-access-check) method as the proper place the handle Authorization before executing or using any action.

Comment: This solution worked with me when building nested resources routes as described [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9474) and after implementing filtering within IndexAction as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query#answer-30560912). My full code is [this](https://github.com/tunecino/Yii2_foundation-apps/blob/master/backend/api/modules/v1/controllers/ImageController.php) and it works fine but I'm also following your question because I'm also interested in different ways to solve it, especially now after you mentioning the checkAccess method.

Comment: Okay... I would like to use the `checkAccess` method.. But it does not seem to trigger at all. restActions are the defaults.

Comment: @Brainfeeder if it doesn't trigger then something should be wrong in code.  In case you did link default actions within `actions()` method then you need to pass the `checkAccess` like it is done [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/e9bec0d24653bf5d330f677f53aafd8c4a7feb1a/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L78). If not then try to open a new question and share your code.