# yii2 rest api implement custom actions

Tags: rest, controller, yii2

For some reason i am getting :

```
{
  "name": "Not Found",
  "message": "Object not found: search",
  "code": 0,
  "status": 404,
  "type": "yii\web\NotFoundHttpException"
}
```

when I try to access a custom action (http://localhost/project/api/web/v1/userfunctions/search) in my yii2 rest api app.
This is what I have in the main.php configuration file

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
    'controller' => 'v1/userfunction',
    'extraPatterns' => ['GET search' => 'search'],
    'tokens' => [
        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
    ]
]
```

And the `UserFunctionController` class has a `actionSearch` method.

Am I missing something here?

When I add a blank action method :

```
public function actions() 
{
  $actions = parent::actions();
  return $actions;
}
```

method the 404 goes away but i get a blank response (status code 200) [This is irrespective of whether the actionSearch is defined or not] Where does the control go in this case?

Here is the `actionSearch()` code

```
 public function actionSearch()
    { 
        $output = UserStatus::findAll();
        return $output;
    }
```

Comment: @Salem Ouerdani,yes. that was a typo. i am using the plural form. edited the question.

Comment: can you add the `actionSearch` function to your question ? all the code you did add should work just fine. maybe actionSearch is throwing an error or not returning an output

Answer (score 0):

By default Yii pluralize controller names for use in endpoints. So if you did not configure the yii\rest\UrlRule::$pluralize property to not do so, then your action should be available within :

```
http://localhost/project/api/web/v1/userfunctions/search
```

---

UPDATE:

```
public function actionSearch()
{ 
    $output = UserStatus::findAll();
    return $output;
}
```

This should throw this PHP error : **Missing argument 1 for yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::findAll()** as the [findAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findAll()-detail) method is expecting a *mixed* argument holding your filtering *conditions*.

You should use this instead :

```
public function actionSearch()
{ 
    $output = UserStatus::find()->all();
    return $output;
}
```

I think your server is not showing error messages correctly. Check its configs, errors log files and be sure to have those lines in your [Entry Script](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-entry-scripts.html) while the app is in **dev** state :

```
// remember to remove them all when deploying to production

   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

   defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
   defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

Comment: I added the function as requested. It somehow is not accessible.

Comment: @DGT I just updated. this post may also help in case if what you need to implement is a filtering action with pagination support : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query

Comment: The thing is I am trying to implement something like  http://api.test.loc/v1/model/xyz where I can call a sub link and send back custom data to the api response. But I keep getting the 404. Inside actionXyz() i will probably have something like Model::find()->select(['name', 'address']). The main concern is how to make the link work. Is 'extraPatterns' => ['GET xyz' => 'xyz'] in the main config and defining the actionXyz in the controller all? Or do i have to do anything else?

Comment: The $actions['index']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'prepareDataProvider']; method you mentioned in the other post works for me. But i want a link of the form api.test.loc/v1/products/xyz and not api.test.loc/v1/products?name=iphone. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes `extraPatterns` will do the work. in my answer in the other post, if you remove the `actions()` function and rename `indexDataProvider()` to `actionXyz()` then you add `'extraPatterns' => ['GET xyz' => 'xyz']` to your urlRules you'll have the same results within this url : `api.test.loc/v1/products/xyz?name=iphone`

Comment: But for some reason i get 
```{ "name": "Not Found", "message": "Object not found: xyz", "code": 0, "status": 404, "type": "yii\web\NotFoundHttpException" } ```

This is the configuration:


```[
                    'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',`
                    'controller' => 'v1/model',
                    'extraPatterns' => ['GET xyz' => 'xyz'],
                    'tokens' => [
                        '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                    ]
                ],
```

Comment: can you try without tokens ? are you receiving data when requesting  `/v1/userfunctions` ? you are not overriding `verbs` inside you controller by declaring them again ?

Comment: taking the ```tokens``` out did the trick. It works perfectly now. And i do not override the ```verbs``` Thank you so much.