# How to send Yii2 RESTful GET request and specify sorting as params

Tags: php, json, rest, sorting, yii2

I want to send GET request to `v1/users` endpoint, where as params I want to specify that I want to do ordering by `priority DESC` and `status ASC`.

As you can see I want to send params that will map to SQL WHERE parts:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE something ORDER BY priority DESC, status ASC`

How I am supposed to specify as params in my HTTP request that I want this sorting ? I think that in order to do this I need to send JSON data in POST request. But that is a problem, because I want GET request not POST. `post/users` means create user, and I want to `get` users.

I guess that I would have to send JSON object like this

`"sort":[
    {"priority":"DESC", "status":"ASC"}
]`

First, is it possible to send params like this when you send GET request ?
Second, how would you send these params using cUrl in PHP ?

Comment: add parameters to the GET request v1/users?priority=desc&status=asc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with the built-in RESTfull API you can use comma for multi attributes sorting and '-' sign for DESC:

```
GET v1/users?sort=-priority,status
```

If using a custom action instead of the built-in onces. be sure to always return a [data provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html#data-providers) instance so the [serializer](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-serializer.html) can generate related pagination and the above params get suppoted:

```
// instead of: return $modelClass::find()->all();
return new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $modelClass::find(),
]);
```

Comment: Do you maybe know how can I sort by related table column ? I have profile filed that is profile relation with profile table. `public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    $fields[] = 'profile';
    return $fields;
}` . So I would like to sort by profile.created_at. Do you know how ?

Comment: In this case I think you'll need to override `$actions['index']['prepareDataProvider']` and add sort to the custom `ActiveDataProvider` instance via `$dataProvider->sort->attributes['profile'] = [..]` before returning it like it is done in [this example](http://www.ramirezcobos.com/2014/04/16/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview-yii2/).

Comment: I personally use the Search Class. it is where I do filtering and sorting. this is one more [example](http://webtips.krajee.com/filter-sort-calculated-related-fields-gridview-yii-2-0/) on how to cutomize the searchClass. and this is [how I use it in REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query/30560912#30560912)

Comment: I have asked full new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474282/how-to-sort-by-related-table-field-when-sending-yii2-rest-get-request