# How replace variables names in searchModel url?

Tags: php, yii2

I have `DocumentSearch` model (that extends `Document` model) in Yii2. When I search, $_GET params are like `/index.php?DocumentSearch[id]=4&DocumentsSearch[name]=Test`

**Q:** How to replace `DocumentSearch[id]` param into `id` and all other attributes? I don't like this way

Comment: Haven't done this before, but you could try to override the formName() method of your DocumentSearch model, returning an empty string http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName()-detail

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query/30560912#30560912

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *MacGyer* said in its comment, you should simply override `formName()` :

```
public function formName()
{
    return '';
}
```

Read more about [`formName()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#formName()-detail) :

> The form name is mainly used by `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` to determine how to name the input fields for the attributes in a model. If the form name is "A" and an attribute name is "b", then the corresponding input name would be "A[b]". **If the form name is an empty string, then the input name would be "b"**.