# Yii2 Url Rewrite with Array parameter

Tags: php, yii2, url-routing

I am trying to rewrite the following url,

```
http://mywebsite.com/web/myContlr?myContlrSearch[id]=900
```

Using Yii2 Url manager i am trying to change the url to be as below,

```
http://mywebsite.com/web/myContlr/900
```

How can this above format possible using urlmanger rules in Yii2. And also I am having multiple parameters like `myContlrSearch[name]`, `myContlrSearch[location]`,.. etc

Please guide me to build the URL restful.

Comment: do you mean like this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query/30560912#30560912 (see original answer vs last update)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to make your API RESTful then You should start from resource naming. Resources should be a nouns in plural form.

For example if you have some class like a "car" then corresponding resource url should looks like `<your-domain>/cars`. In this case `GET /cars` will be a method to get a collection of cars, and `GET /cars/900` -- a method to get specific car with ID=900.

Next, if your  parameters are needed for filtering resource collection then you should add them as query parameters to collection resource url, like this: `/cars?vendor=ferrari&count=10`. If your parameters are needed to specify instance properties (when you create or update some object), then you should include them into a request body.

For instance creation you should use url of resource collection: `POST /cars`. And for updating an instance -- `PUT /cars/<id>`.

Lets look on your particular case. You have some resource named `myContlr` (i hope this is just example name), so `myContlr` should be an noun which express a object name. Your `myContlrSearch` in query parameters looks like some search criteria object, so it can be passed as array or as json in query parameters (it's [better do not use request body for GET requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)). Using array/json/any-other-structure here will not affect your routing -- this should be within the scope of responsibility of the controller.

But if you want to create new object or update existing one, then you should use `POST /myContrlr` or `PUT /myContrlr/900` and then pass your object in request body (of type `application/json` or `application/xml`).

Then your routing config can looks as follows:

```
$config['components']['urlManager'] = [
    ...
    'rules' => [
        'GET myContlr/<id:\d+>' => 'myContlr/view',
        'PUT myContlr/<id:\d+>' => 'myContlr/update',
        'DELETE myContlr/<id:\d+>' => 'myContlr/delete',
        'GET myContlr' => 'myContlr/index',
```

To learn more about building RESTful API in Yii2: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html

For further reading: http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api