# Cant use tockens and extrapattern together for REST services in Yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

[Yii2 REST query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522462/yii2-rest-query)

I found this for using custom action in the controller for that i added the extrapattern mentioned in the  above link

And its working fine when we search .but cant use the normal actions for the controller

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/country',
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET search' => 'search'
                    ],
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                ]

            ]
        ],        
    ]
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all

this solved my problem after lots of trying..

```
          'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/country',
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'GET search' => 'search'
                    ],                 
            ],
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
                'controller' => 'v1/country',
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                ]

            ],

        ],
```