# How to make a secure user authentication (post call) in Yii2 RESTful Web Services?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Yii2 RESTful Web Services takes POST as CREATE in ActiveController.

How can I send by POST the username/password through my API, and take this as a user authentication method, instead of a "create" action ?

Answer (score 0):

Add URL rule to your config and necessary actions.

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            'POST /auth/<action:\w+>' => 'auth/<action>',
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: I have already rules in my components, and when I add that one, it fails. I'm using this config from yii2-advanced-api : https://github.com/deerawan/yii2-advanced-api/blob/master/api/config/main.php

Comment: you will get some ideas from here..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167458/cant-use-tockens-and-extrapattern-together-for-rest-services-in-yii2